AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int' ---> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float32_t' but got 'double'
Code
I'm running a Python code which has the following statements:
            # do NMS
            dets = np.hstack((boxes, scores[:, np.newaxis])).astype(np.float32, copy=False)
            keep = nms(dets, 0.3) # -> *** Error is thrown here :(
            dets = dets[keep, :]


Data
The data shown by the debugger is:


Error
Eventually, the code throws this error:

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.

At this line of code:
from .nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms, cpu_soft_nms

def nms(dets, thresh):
    """Dispatch to either CPU or GPU NMS implementations."""

    if dets.shape[0] == 0:
        return []
    return cpu_nms(dets, thresh) # -> *** Error is thrown here :(

Tried 1
I don't see any usage of np.int but I see that np.float32 is used as can be seen above. As suggested here, I replaced np.float32 with np.float32_. Then I get another error:

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float32_'

Tried 2
I replaced np.float32 with np.float_, then this error is received:

File "nms/cpu_nms.pyx", line 17, in nms.cpu_nms.cpu_nms


ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float32_t' but got 'double'

Question
What else I can try to resolve the error?

Please show your complete traceback

Just in case it might be helpful, the line of code throwing the errors is this: https://github.com/jhb86253817/PIPNet/blob/b9eab58816437403a34aa5bc3adeafe5081fd36b/FaceBoxesV2/utils/nms_wrapper.py#L15

No. It's this line https://github.com/jhb86253817/PIPNet/blob/b9eab58816437403a34aa5bc3adeafe5081fd36b/FaceBoxesV2/utils/nms/cpu_nms.pyx#L29

This line of code is throwing the error: https://github.com/jhb86253817/PIPNet/blob/b9eab58816437403a34aa5bc3adeafe5081fd36b/FaceBoxesV2/faceboxes_detector.py#L77

@OneCricketeer Thanks. For some reason, my debugger doesn't go through that line at all.

You'll need to downgrade Numpy to a version that was used 4 years ago when this repo was last updated

@OneCricketeer People have recently run this code: https://github.com/SimonGiebenhain/MonoNPHM/issues/3#issuecomment-2187770498 I wonder if all of them have downgraded the Numpy version?

Maybe. Or they're not using the same functions that you are

@OneCricketeer My Numpy version being used is 1.26.4 I'm going to replace it with 1.23 and try again.

Numpy version mismatch
I doublechecked the Numpy version on my activated Conda environment, it was 1.26.4:
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
1.26.4

It was strange since I had installed version 1.23 as suggested by the repository:

Conda not using Numpy from activated env
So, I figured out that for some reason, the Conda environment is using Numpy from:
/home/arisa/.local/bin/pip3

Rather than from the activated env:
/home/arisa/.conda/envs/mononphm/bin/pip3

Solution
So, I removed all the Numpy versions from the system altogether:
pip3 uninstall numpy

And re-installed the version suggested by the repository inside the Conda env:
/home/arisa/.conda/envs/mononphm/bin/pip3 install numpy==1.23

Now the error is resolved :)
Note that I had previously run into a similar problem before: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mononphm'
